# Why might IsDialogMessage() never return?

Tags: winapi

I am debugging an application which, in its message loop, calls [IsDialogMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645498(VS.85).aspx).  Occasionally, IsDialogMessage() never returns (where never is an interval greater than 1 hour).  Based on the symbols for user32.dll available from Microsoft's symbol server, it appears to be stuck in [GetNextDlgGroupItem()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645492(VS.85).aspx) (or an internal variant of the same), iterating over some set of windows.

The application is multithreaded and frequently receives notification of external events, which arrive as DCOM calls.  I suspect that such a call is handled incorrectly in a way that corrupts some window state.  If I can learn what sort of state corruption might cause an infinite loop in IsDialogMessage(), I think I will be more easily able to identify the source of the corruption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you maybe disabling controls (using `::EnableWindow()`) without checking first whether that control has the focus? If yes, then the focus gets lost and GetNextDlgGroupItem() gets confused.

Comment: That is possible; there are many controls in play and some may be disabled.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but answering for posterity since no one here mentioned it.

More than likely what is going on is trouble with the windows manager determining where to forward a message. If you have a hierarchy of windows, as you probably do, then you need to ensure that non-top-level windows that contain controls themselves must have the WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT style set. If it is a dialog, you use the DS_CONTROL style. The presence of these flags modify the behavior of IsDialogMessage; they identify a window as having its own controls which can receive focus and handle tab order, etc, rather than just being a control itself.

For example, if you have a main frame window, which has a child window with WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, which has a child window *without* WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, which has a child window that has focus, and you hit TAB, you will likely encounter an infinite loop at the same place you mention.

Setting the second child's extended style to include WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this can happen is if you reparent a modeless dialog.  At least this can happen with wxWidgets...

Answer (score 0):

I've made some investigation, trying to answer this question. But only in situation, when parent window is in native MFC project and child is a managed C# Windows Forms. If you have such situation, then you may try 3 resolutions:

1. Run MFC dialog message loop on Windows Forms side. Here is more info: [Integrate Windows Forms Into Your MFC Applications Through C++ Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163605.aspx)
2. Create 2 threads: one for Windows Forms dialog and one for native dialog. Here you can create dialog in Windows Forms, then with SetParent() set it's parent to native dialog. But be ware: if you add TabControl to Windows Forms, than hang with "IsDialogMessage() never return" will occur.
3. Make a wrapper for Windows Forms dialog to use in native project. For ex., wrapper may be WPF, see here: [Windows Form as child window of an unmanaged app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381298/windows-form-as-child-window-of-an-unmanaged-app)

I've taken information mostly from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229600.aspx

And the temporary cure can be to change focus behavior. For example, disable them, or SetFocus() to parent or child windows only. But I strongly recommend to investigate the real reason, why IsDialogMessage() never return in your case.